# Like icon and Likes counter does not refresh automatically

Tags: javascript, django

I am trying to get a Web page that updates the Likes counter when a user clicks on the Likes icon (similar to Twitter, now X): I am using JavaScript and Django (I am a newbie in both).

I am facing this issue:

1. when I click on Like icon ("thumbs up" by default) the Like counter increase but the Like icon does not change to a "thumbs down" icon and indeed if I click on Like icon again then the Like counter increase again.
2. Once I refresh the page manually the Like icon appears as thumb down.

I would like that:

1. when I click on Like icon ("thumbs up" by default) the Like counter increase and the Like icon changes to a "thumbs down" icon
2. when I click again on Like icon (it is a "thumb down" icon now) then the Like counter decrease and the Like icon changes to a "thumbs up" icon
3. the above should be gotten without requiring a reload of the entire page (I have to refresh the page manually right now)

Please find below my code:

**index.html**

```
{% extends "network/layout.html" %}

{% block body %}

    <!-- Javascript code -->
    <script>
        function getCookie(name) {
            const value = `; ${document.cookie}`;
            const parts = value.split(`; ${name}=`);
            if(parts.length == 2)
                return parts.pop().split(';').shift();
        }

        function submitHandler(id) {
            const textareaValue = document.getElementById(`textarea_${id}`).value;
            const content = document.getElementById(`content_${id}`);
            const modal = document.getElementById(`modal_edit_post_${id}`);

            fetch(`/edit/${id}`, {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    "Content-type": "application/json",
                    "X-CSRFToken": getCookie("csrftoken")
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    content: textareaValue
                })
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(result => {
                content.innerHTML = result.data;

                modal.classList.remove('show');
                modal.setAttribute('aria-hidden', 'true');
                modal.setAttribute('style', 'display: none');

                const modalsBackdrops = document.getElementsByClassName('modal-backdrop');
                for(let i=0; i<modalsBackdrops.length; i++) {
                    document.body.removeChild(modalsBackdrops[i]);
                }
            })
        }

        // Like handler with Ajax
        //
        function likeHandler(id, whoYouLiked) {
            const btn = document.getElementById(`${id}`);
            const likesCountSpan = document.getElementById(`likes_count_${id}`);

            if (whoYouLiked.indexOf(id) >= 0) {
                var liked = true;
            } 
            else {
                var liked = false;
            }

            const likeURL = liked ? `/remove_like/${id}` : `/add_like/${id}`;
            $.ajax({
                url: likeURL,
                method: 'GET',
                success: function (response) {
                    btn.classList.toggle('fas', response.liked === true);
                    btn.classList.toggle('far', response.liked === false);
                    btn.classList.toggle('fa-thumbs-up', response.liked === false);
                    btn.classList.toggle('fa-thumbs-down', response.liked === true);
                    likesCountSpan.textContent = response.likes_count;
                }
            });
            liked = !liked;
        }

        function updateLikesCount(postId, newCount) {
            const likesCountSpan = document.getElementById(`likes_count_${postId}`);
            likesCountSpan.textContent = newCount;
        }
    </script>

    <!-- Rest of the code -->
    <h1>All Posts</h1>
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <div class="new-post">
            <div class="row"><h2>New Post</h2></div>
            <form action="{% url 'newPost' %}" method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <textarea name="content" row="4" cols="100"></textarea>
                <br/>
                <input type="submit" value="Post" class="btn btn-primary"/>
            </form>
        </div>
    {% endif %}

    <div class="all-posts mx-5">
        {% for post in posts_of_the_page %}
            <div class="row post">
                <h5 class="username"><a href="{% url 'profile' user_id=post.user.id %}">@{{ post.user }}</a></h5>
                <h6 class="content" id="content_{{ post.id }}">{{ post.content }}</h6>
                <p class="date">{{ post.date }}</p>

                <!-- Edit button -->
                {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                    {% if user == post.user %}
                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-around">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_edit_post_{{ post.id }}">Edit</button>
                        </div>

                        <div class="modal fade" id="modal_edit_post_{{ post.id }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labellebdy="modal_edit_post_{{ post.id }}_label" aria-hidden="true">
                            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                        <h5>Edit Post</h5>
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                        <textarea rows="5" id="textarea_{{ post.id }}" class="form-control" name="content">{{ post.content }}</textarea>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="submitHandler({{ post.id }})">Save changes</button>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    {% else %}
                        <!--{% if post.id in whoYouLiked %}
                            <button class="btn btn-info fa fa-thumbs-down col-1" onclick="likeHandler({{ post.id }}, {{ whoYouLiked }})" id="{{ post.id }}"></button>
                        {% else %}
                            <button class="btn btn-info fa fa-thumbs-up col-1" onclick="likeHandler({{ post.id }}, {{ whoYouLiked }})" id="{{ post.id }}"></button>
                        {% endif %}-->
                        
                        <button class="btn btn-info like-button" id="{{ post.id }}" onclick="likeHandler({{ post.id }}, {{ whoYouLiked }})">
                            {% if post.id in whoYouLiked %}
                                <i class="fa fa-thumbs-down"></i>
                            {% else %}
                                <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i>
                            {% endif %}
                        </button>
                        <span id="likes_count_{{ post.id }}" class="likes-count">{{ post.likes_count }}</span>

                    {% endif %}
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>

    <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
        <ul class="pagination d-flex justify-content-center">
            {% if posts_of_the_page.has_previous %}
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ posts_of_the_page.previous_page_number }}">Previous</a></li>
            {% endif %}

            {% if posts_of_the_page.has_next %}
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ posts_of_the_page.next_page_number }}">Next</a></li>
            {% endif %}
        </ul>
    </nav>
{% endblock %}
```

**layout.html**

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>{% block title %}Social Network{% endblock %}</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link href="{% static 'network/styles.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>

        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'index' %}">Network</a>
          
            <div>
              <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'profile' user_id=user.id %}"><strong>{{ user.username }}</strong></a>
                    </li>
                {% endif %}
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'index' %}">All Posts</a>
                </li>
                {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'following' %}">Following</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Log Out</a>
                    </li>
                {% else %}
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'login' %}">Log In</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'register' %}">Register</a>
                    </li>
                {% endif %}
              </ul>
            </div>
          </nav>
        
        <div class="body">
            {% block body %}
            {% endblock %}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Please I would appreciate your help.

Comment: are there any errors in your browsers *developer* tools console?

Comment: Hi! No: there is any error in the browser developer´s console, neither in the Django server console

Answer (score 0):

I solved it changing my LikeHandler function, in this updated version I use buttons instead of icons:

**index.html**

```
function likeHandler(id) {
            const btn = document.getElementById(`${id}`);
            const likesCountSpan = document.getElementById(`likes_count_${id}`);
            const liked = btn.getAttribute("data-liked") === "true";
            const likeURL = liked ? `/remove_like/${id}` : `/add_like/${id}`;

            $.ajax({
                url: likeURL,
                method: 'GET',
                success: function (response) {
                    btn.setAttribute("data-liked", response.liked);
                    if (response.liked) {
                        btn.textContent = "Unlike";
                    } 
                    else {
                        btn.textContent = "Like";
                    }            
                    likesCountSpan.innerHTML = `Likes: ${response.likes_count}`;
                }
            });
        }
```